# Using TextWriter.Synchronized or having lock in multithreaded file IO - C# WPF .net 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, streamwriter, textwriter

Ok there are 2 ways of writing text to a file in multi threaded system

Which one is better than other

First case : having a static object to lock streamwriter and do operations

Second case having :

```
     TextWriter twWaitingToBeFetched;
     twWaitingToBeFetched = TextWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter(stringPath, true));
     twWaitingToBeFetched.WriteLine(srNewComposedUrl);
     twWaitingToBeFetched.Flush();
```

Now which one is better do you think and why ?

I need multiple threads tasks to write same stream

C# .net 4.5 - WPF application

Comment: Do you need multiple threads to write to the file using the same stream? Or can multiple threads use their own stream to the same file to append content?

Comment: @Frode I need multiple threads to write same stream

Comment: Both are almost same except that lock field shouldn't be static(if `twWaitingToBeFetched` is instance field). static locks will synchronize two unrelated instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the 2nd variant locking is implicit and hidden. Calling code does know anything about the locks. In fact it might wrongly assume that two calls to `WriteLine` are atomic and will appear one after the other in the output.

Use explicit locking so that you can better control what operations appear to be atomic.

---

```
 TextWriter twWaitingToBeFetched;
 twWaitingToBeFetched = TextWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter(stringPath, true));
 twWaitingToBeFetched.WriteLine(srNewComposedUrl);
 twWaitingToBeFetched.Flush();
```

This does not synchronize anything because each `WriteLine` is dispatched on a new, independent synchronized writer. You also need to properly dispose objects and not call `Flush` unnecessarily.

Comment: If i don't call flush and if app crashes i it is not writing everything what is the more proper way ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG that's a valid use case for Flush.